# How to retrieve real time traffic and display it onto an admin dashboard?

Tags: php, javascript, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm looking for a way to retrieve and then display (with some Highcharts - like library) the current traffic we have on the website. The same way google analytics displays it on the gioogle analytics admin dashboard, but I'd like to retrieve with some API and display it directly on our custom dashboard.

After reading through the complete google analytics documentation, I've understood that

> "Google Analytics API doesn’t support real-time stats yet… but this is
>   still useful if you want to display pageviews or number of visits on
>   your site and have it automatically update."

So my question is, is there another API to retrieve and display the current/instant traffic on a website on our custom admin dashboard. Or, is there a workaround (with AJAX ?) to do so with the google analytics API ? ( i've seen that you can retrieve the amount visitors on a given perido, so even if this is not real time, fo now it gets as close as I can to my goal)

I'm working with php and javscript

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - the current API doesn't currently support true **real-time** statistics.  It is the most highly requested feature though:

[Google Analytics developer issues and feature requests](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/list)

[Access to Real Time Data](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=154&colspec=ID%20Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary)

We develop services which integrate with the API.  On average I estimate the latency is about 1-3 hours.  I believe the larger your dataset it the longer the latency.